# Operações Matemáticas em ARM-M4 travam quando interrupção PWM está ligada

Tags: c, float, arm

Quando desligo a interrupção de timer overflow do `PWM` (+- 15Khz) as operações ocorrem normalmente. Mas quando ela está ligada o processador se perde em operações de ponto flutuante. Acompanho pelo debug em modo step mas em algum momento o debug não retorna e fica como se estivesse rodando só dando outro pause que sempre cai na interrupção descrita.

Estou usando um `K20` sem FPU da Freescale e perguntei por lá no community mas nem ligaram.
Já aumentei o Stack mas nada de melhorar.
Tive o mesmo problema com um `S08PA`, mas neste era só baixar a ocorrência do timer overflow (de 20Khz para 15Khz) que funcionava corretamente.

**Edit:**
Não de fato um firmware pois estou travado neste problema. Somente há a interrupção do `PWM` e a rotina para gerar a tabela Seno.

```
// Gerador da tabela
void PWMInit(){

float a;
int i,r;

// Combine mode Pulse = CN+1 - CN
// Complementary mode : N+1 = Inv(N) 

Motor.DutyMax = FTM0_MOD - FTM0_CNTIN;
Motor.DutyZero = Motor.DutyMax >> 1;


Motor.Frequencia = 60;

Motor.MaxSamples = PWMFreq / Motor.Frequencia;
Motor.VMod = (Motor.DutyMax / 60) * Motor.Frequencia;
Motor.IncTabela = (float) 1000.0f / Motor.MaxSamples;
Motor.Div = (((long) MAXTABELA / Motor.VMod));
/*
for (i=0, a=0; i < Motor.MaxSamples; i++, a += Motor.IncTabela ) {
    r = SinT[(int)(a + 0.5f)];
    r = r / Motor.Div;
    r = Motor.DutyZero + r;
    TabelaGerada[i] =  (uint16_t) r;
}
*/
float ri = (2*PI) / Motor.MaxSamples;
float rr = 0;
for (i=0; i < Motor.MaxSamples; i++) {
    TabelaGerada[i] =  Motor.DutyZero * ((float) 1.0f + sin(rr));
    rr = rr + ri;
}

SetW(100);
SetV(500);
SetU(900);

FTM0_SYNC |= (FTM_SYNC_SWSYNC_MASK | (1 << 7)); 


}

// Interrupção
PE_ISR(EstouroDoTimerFTM0){
(void)(FTM0_SC == 0U);

Counter = 0;
}
```

Comment: Poderia postar o código do firmware?

Comment: Faz tempo que não programo para microcontroladores, mas as interrupções default de hardware que eu não usava eu colocava uma instrução IRET. Não sei se é o teu caso.

Comment: Usando C não preciso desta instrução ASM.

Comment: Teu caso parece ser mesmo excesso de interrupções, já que ao diminuir a frequência você diz que funciona. Se você necessita de uma taxa de interrupção muita alta o processador deve ser capaz de executar as outras tarefas e no caso cálculos demandam muitos ciclos. Por isto é que pode se perder na depuração.

Comment: Eu diminui o tempo das ocorrências para algo em torno de 1ms (comparado aos 50uS), mas nada de melhorar.

Comment: Fábio, recomendo a técnica dividir para conquistar. Tente montar teu código somente uma operação de ponto flutuante e deixe teu timer no frequência de 50uS e veja se funciona corretamente com a depuração. Assim você elimina o fator carga como fonte de teus problemas. O próximo passo vai depender do resultado.

Answer (score 1):

Peguei. Acontece que o Wizard Processor Expert não desabilitava as interrupções dos dois ultimos canais que não eram utilizados (motores somente usam 6 canais). Assim os canais 6 e 7 estavam com interrupções de 'channel match' habilitadas e sendo disparadas em locais indefinidos.